# Reverse a custom nested list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, nested, reverse

I am working on trying to reverse a nested list in Haskell.  I am aware that nested lists are not a thing in Haskell so I defined one:

```
data NestedList a = Elem a | SubList [NestedList a]
```

I also have a flatten function:

```
flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Elem x) = [x]
flatten (SubList x) = concatMap flatten x
```

Now I wish to write my reverse function.  The function is defined as:

```
myreverse :: NestedList a -> NestedList a
```

Which I think makes sense because I'm just rearranging the elements within the list.

I understand how to write a basic reverse function, and I also know that for Haskell's standard lists reverse is already defined.

My question is: how do I deal with the case where the head of the list is also a list?  What I know needs to happen is that I reverse the head of the list and put it back onto the reverse of the tail. But how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not this way

```
rev :: NestedList a -> NestedList a
rev (Elem a) = Elem a
rev (SubList xs) = SubList $ map rev $ reverse xs
```

if you add deriving (Show) to your data definition,

```
Prelude> rev $ SubList [Elem 1, SubList [Elem 2, Elem 3]]
SubList [SubList [Elem 3,Elem 2],Elem 1]

Prelude> rev $ SubList [Elem 1, SubList []]
SubList [SubList [],Elem 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your nested list is actually a tree with elements at leavess:

```
                 SubList
               /         \
        SubList           Elem 4
    /      |      \
Elem 1   Elem 2   Elem 3
```

So your `myreverse` would be a horizontal flip, i.e. recursive `reverse` of each list in `SubList`, as other answer points out.

The lesson here: Visualising data-structures helps to understand and implement actions on them.